# Solving SDE with Ito Integral inside drift

Tags: brownian-motion, finance, stochastic-differential-equations

I want to solve a 2 equation system of SDEs:

$dF_{1t} = (\mu_1 + \rho_{11}F_{1t})dt + dW_{1t}\\
dF_{2t} = (\mu_2 + \rho_{21}F_{1t} + \rho_{22}F_{2t})dt + dW_{2t}
$

with $F_{10} = F_{20} = 0$. Here $W_{1t}$ and $W_{2t}$ are 2 independent Brownian Motions. I solved the first equation as a regular Ornstein Uhlenbeck process to obtain:
\begin{align*}
F_{1t} = (e^{\rho_{11}t} - 1)\frac{\mu_1}{\rho_{11}} + e^{\rho_{11}t} \int_0^t e^{-\rho_{11}s}dW_{1s}
\end{align*}
I now substitute this solution into the second equation to obtain the following SDE:
\begin{align*}
dF_{2t} &= \bigg(\mu_2 + (e^{\rho_{11}t}-1)\frac{\mu_1 \rho_{21}}{\rho_{11}} + \rho_{21}e^{\rho_{11}t}\int_0^t e^{-\rho_{11}s}dW_{1s} + \rho_{22}F_{2t}\bigg)dt + dW_{2t} 
\end{align*}
My question is: How can I solve equations of the second form, which basically have an Ito integral inside the drift? I need a strong solution.

Comment: I think I'd go for using Girsanov's theorem to obtain a weak solution.

Comment: @Chaos ,  Thanks for the pointer. I should have been clear. I was looking for a strong solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system of SDEs can be written in matrix vector form as
$$\tag{1}
d\boldsymbol{F}_t=(\boldsymbol{\mu}+\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{F})\,dt+d\boldsymbol{W}_t
$$
where
$$
\boldsymbol{A}=\left(\begin{matrix}\rho_{11} & \rho_{12}\\\rho_{21} &\rho_{22}\end{matrix}\right)\,.
$$
The solution to (1) is
$$
\boldsymbol{F}_t=e^{\boldsymbol{A}t}\Big(\boldsymbol{F}_0+\int_0^t e^{-\boldsymbol{A}s}\boldsymbol{\mu}\,ds+\int_0^t e^{-\boldsymbol{A}s}\,dW_s\Big)\,.
$$
This can easily be checked using Ito's formula. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Linear_SDE:_general_case).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kurt . I was wondering if there was any way to derive this using first principles?

Comment: My way of deriving this was to look up the 1D case in Wikipedia and generalize it to the matrix vector case. The only first principle I can think of is that we are all standing on the shoulders of very great men and women.

Comment: Hahah agreed touche`